# Find path to offending non-Serializable member variable

Tags: java, serialization

In Java, Serialization makes reading and writing objects to streams REALLY easy.  For instance, the following code snippet is mostly all it takes to write objects to a stream:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = ... //Initialize your output stream
Object toWrite = ...         //Initialize what you want to write here
oos.writeObject(toWrite);    //Writes the object to the stream
oos.flush();
```

This will work just fine, provided that `toWrite`'s class implements the `Serializable` interface, AND that all of `toWrite`'s non-`transient` member variables are also `Serializable`.  In other words, the entire Object hierarchy you are trying to send via the `toWrite` reference must be `Serializable`. Assume that the only problem with this code is that something inside `toWrite` isn't `Serializable`.

If the hierarchy isn't completely `Serializable`, the call to `oos.writeObject(toWrite)` throws a `java.io.NotSerializableException`.  This is all fine and good, except that the Exception doesn't give you quite everything you need to fix the problem quickly.  It will tell you what class couldn't be serialized.  Your stack trace might look something like this:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: some.package.and.ClassIDidntExplicitlyReference
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at my.package.MyClass.codeThatWroteTheOffendingObject(MyClass.java:###)
```

This sort of points you in the right direction, but in cases that involve deep Object hierarchies referenced by `toWrite`, it's not always clear where the offending class reference came from.  Let's say I assign `toWrite` to an instance of `MyClass` and my instance of `MyClass` has a member Object reference called `nonSerializableReference` that has been set to an instance of `ClassIDidntExplicitlyReference`, which is not `Serializable`.  I'd like to see something like the following printed out:

```
my.package.MyClass.nonSerializableReference instanceof some.package.and.ClassIDidntExplicitlyReference
```

I know this problem probably doesn't have a quick solution, and will likely involve using Reflections.  Has anyone here on SO done this before and if so, would you mind sharing your insight?

**Answer**

I ended up using Reflection's `Field` and `Modifier` class to find the path.  Unfortunately, I can't share my code (against company policy), but I can show you my output.  Class A holds an instance of B, B holds an instance of C, and C holds an instance of D.  All are `Serializable` except for D.  I ended up using Depth-First-Search to find the path:

```
A.b -> 
  B.c -> 
    C.d instanceof class D
```

If I make `C.d` transient, the search yields no results.  Pretty cool!

Comment: You want to change Java Serialization implementation, look for some other implementations such as JBoss Serialization, maybe that has your request, or post a request on Oracle Java community....

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm asking for.  I don't want to change the Serialization implementation, I simply want to know the path from `myObject` to the member variable that caused the problem.  After that, I would either decide how to make that member variable implement `Serializable` or make it `transient`.  *That* decision totally depends on what the path to the offending variable ends up being.

Comment: 'It also only works if you don't have any Serialization loops': that is not correct. Serialization copes with cyclic object graphs just fine. See the Object Serialization Specification.

Comment: Intersting.  I could have sworn I ran into a problem with Serialization years ago where `A` had a reference to `B` and vice versa, and I ended up getting a `StackOverflowError` when calling `writeObject` on an instance of `A`.  That was a long time ago though, perhaps it was in some other language and I'm just not remembering correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange question - you're wanting to determine at runtime what you should be doing at compile time.  In theory, the path to the object *shouldn't* matter - you need to find the objects that reference things that aren't serializable to fix your code.

That said, you could write a simple recursive tree crawler using reflection.  That said, you might be able to get away with implementing your own ObjectInputStream that logs the objects coming in appropriately.  I recommend taking a look at the [source](http://docjar.com/html/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.java.html) for more detail

Comment: Agreed, it's strange, but sometimes it's not always obvious at compile time what might not be Serializable.  I'm basically writing a distributed computing framework that several developers will be porting a very large, complex, old code base to use.  Some of the object hierarchies they will be dealing with are very deep, and the quickest way to find Serialization problems is to run it and see what happens.  I do have a log system that knows when NotSerializableExceptions occur, so it will be responsible for printing the path to objects that cause the exceptions.

Answer (score 17):

Pass the flag `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` to the JVM and it should give you exactly the information you want, when a `NotSerializableException` is thrown.

Comment: That should be the preferred answer to this question. It immediately helped me to sole the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I also implemented the crawler thing you talked about. If somebody is still interested in it, I presented the code here: [A good way to find unserializable fields in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25074673/a-good-way-to-find-unserializable-fields-in-java)

Comment: Given that this provides a usable implementation (which I just used to good effect myself, thank you!), this should really be the accepted answer.