# A good way to find unserializable fields in Java

Tags: java, serialization, find, field

I have a quite complex Java object to serialize (which worked fine a couple of weeks ago). After having implemented a lot in the meantime, the serialization now fails throwing the following exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D
```

I have inspected all classes which seemed relevant, but could not find a field in any of them holding a Graphics2D type (or a similar type such as BufferedImage or the like). As I see it, the problem could also be that I'm using a class (from a library or so) which itself is serializable, but has a field of the unserializable type Graphics2D.

So, my question is: is there a "good" way to find the place where the serialization fails? Inspecting all classes and all changes made seems to be hardly feasible.

Thank you in advance

Lukas

PS. Here is the full stack trace of the exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3697)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3697)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3697)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(ObjectOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:482)
    at java.awt.Container.writeObject(Container.java:3697)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Window.java:2943)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.save(AWTEventMulticaster.java:946)
    at java.awt.Window.writeObject(Window.java:2931)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at eas.simulation.SerializableSimulationState.save(SerializableSimulationState.java:121)
    at eas.plugins.standard.visualization.ControlPanel.actionPerformed(ControlPanel.java:202)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library class can be assumed to be correctly serializable, i.e. to declare all non-serializable fields as transient, and therefore *shouldn't* be the source of the error.

If your code is using ContextedRuntimeExceptions, they are an exception to the above rule because the objects they reference may not be serializable, and this is [noted in the Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/exception/ContextedRuntimeException.html) at the methods addContextValue() and setContextValue(). If context values are the problem, it would explain why the suspect classes got a reference to a Graphics2D object without having such a field.

I have had limited success replicating NotSerializableException for SunGraphics2D without leaving an obvious field with "Graphics" in its name laying around, which could be due to testing on a simpler class structure. I found that in addition to contexted exceptions, collections were a good suspect but only if they used raw types. Collections could also cause intermittent failures if they were only sometimes populated with Graphics.

Depending on your application, Ben Lawry's automated solution to a similar issue [may be easier to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734431/find-path-to-offending-non-serializable-member-variable?rq=1) than manually hunting for the above. If that path works, it will likely be more thorough as well. Can you get a stack trace?

Comment: Ok, I DON'T use ContextedRuntimeExceptions (at least not intentionally), but I will look for Collections - you mean that, e.g., a Collection is serializable as long as it's empty (or in the raw case if it contains only serializable objects), but not if a Graphics object is added? I will add a complete stack trace to my original post. (I will also look into Ben Lawry's solution.) Thanks for the many good suggestions.

Comment: Update: Checking the collections didn't solve the problem. Trying to narrow down the set of possible classes, I made a "binary search" in SVN revisions to find the revision in which the problem first occurred. Unfortunatelly, it turned out that the only change to this revision was a change in the program parameters, not in the classes - and it was a different field on which serialization failed (this was actually easy to correct). However, as I haven't committed the original parameters, I'm now not even able to reproduce the error!! I will continue looking into it and post major insights :-)

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I meant about collections. Glad to hear you have serialization working again! It's interesting that a parameter change seems to have affected which fields are / are not serialized. I'm also glad to see only AWT componets rather than Swing components are getting serialized--all the better for when Swing is updated. :) Where did the problem field finally turn up?

Comment: To be honest, I still haven't found the exact place. Serialization is still a little bit mystical to me. I have changed several things and I THINK it should work now, but as I cannot restore the original parameter setup, I cannot be sure... by any means, I never found that obscure Graphics2D field. I have, however, implemented a crawler which searches for unserializable fields. It is very helpful to me and maybe others can use it, too (see my own answer to the question).

Answer (score 9):

Okay, inspired by the idea of Ben Lawry who, however, did not present an actual implementation, I have also programmed a class crawler which finds "unserializable fields", i.e., non-static, non-transient fields that are either not implementing the Serializable interface themselves or contain fields that are non-static, non-transient and do not implement the Serializable interface.

You can add several classes to be tested in the list in the main method (see comment). The output is a list of fields from these classes or any referenced classes that are not serializable by the above definition (which, however, is not exactly equal to the actually serializable fields, but captures a superset of the latter); for each field which itself does implement the Serializable interface, a list of fields referenced in the type of that field is given which cause the field being not serializable (if the list is empty the field itself does not implement the Serializable interface).

Here is the code, hope it helps others, too:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Crawler {
    public static boolean crawlRecursively(Field field, HashSet<Class<?>> alreadyCrawled, HashMap<Field, HashSet<String>> badFields) {
        if (alreadyCrawled.contains(field.getType())) {
            return !badFields.keySet().contains(field);
        }

        alreadyCrawled.add(field.getType());

        if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())
                || Modifier.isTransient(field.getModifiers())
                || field.getType().isPrimitive()) {
            return true;
        } else if (Serializable.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            boolean allGood = true;

            for (Field f : field.getType().getDeclaredFields()) {
                boolean isGood = crawlRecursively(f, alreadyCrawled, badFields);
                if (!isGood) {
                    if (!badFields.containsKey(field)) {
                        badFields.put(field, new HashSet<>());
                    }
                    badFields.get(field).add(f.getType().getSimpleName() + " " + f.getName());
                    allGood = false;
                }
            }

            return allGood;
        } else {
            if (!badFields.containsKey(field)) {
                badFields.put(field, new HashSet<>());
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    public static HashMap<Field, HashSet<String>> initiateCrawling(Collection<Class<?>> roots) {
        HashMap<Field, HashSet<String>> badFields = new HashMap<>();

        for (Class<?> root : roots) {
            for (Field f : root.getDeclaredFields()) {
                crawlRecursively(f, new HashSet<>(), badFields);
            }
        }

        return badFields;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Class<?>> roots = new LinkedList<>();
        roots.add(JComponent.class); // ADD YOUR CLASSES HERE.
        HashMap<Field, HashSet<String>> badFields = initiateCrawling(roots);

        if (badFields.keySet().size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("All fields are serializable (not having checked the given class(es) themselves).");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The following fields are not serializable in the class tree(s) given by " + roots + ":");
        }

        for (Field field : badFields.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("<UnSer> "
                    + field.getType().getSimpleName() + " " 
                    + field.getName() + " (" 
                    + field.getDeclaringClass().getName() + ") => " + badFields.get(field));
        }
    }
}
```

Example output for class JComponent:

```
The following fields are not serializable in the class tree(s) given by [class javax.swing.JComponent]:
<UnSer> Border border (javax.swing.JComponent) => []
<UnSer> ComponentInputMap windowInputMap (javax.swing.JComponent) => [JComponent component]
<UnSer> VetoableChangeSupport vetoableChangeSupport (javax.swing.JComponent) => [VetoableChangeListenerMap map, Object source]
<UnSer> SingleSelectionModel selectionModel (javax.swing.JPopupMenu) => []
<UnSer> JPopupMenu popupMenu (javax.swing.JComponent) => [SingleSelectionModel selectionModel]
<UnSer> Object source (java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport) => []
<UnSer> VetoableChangeListenerMap map (java.beans.VetoableChangeSupport) => []
<UnSer> JComponent component (javax.swing.ComponentInputMap) => [VetoableChangeSupport vetoableChangeSupport, JPopupMenu popupMenu, Border border, InputVerifier inputVerifier]
<UnSer> InputVerifier inputVerifier (javax.swing.JComponent) => []
```